# Adobe Air app native alert message

Tags: air

I have an Adobe Air application which goal is to open an URL and after 3 seconds I am closing the app with `NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();`
The problem appears after 30 seconds approximately, when I receive an native alert message on my phone with this message: "Unfortunately myapp is stopped.". 
I don't want this to happen,  which can be the problem, it is related about something in the xml file? thanks!

```
function f():void{
string = e.split("|");
navigateToURL(new URLRequest(string[1]),"_blank");
setTimeout(function(){
        NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();
},3000);
```

}

Comment: Android? iOS? It's for sure not supported on iOS. On Android, I believe there have been some recent changes to how apps are meant to be closed. Are you using the latest SDK (AIR 3.9.x, or beta 4.0)?

Comment: Android... Yes I am using 3.9 SDK.

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing this rather than allowing system multi-tasking to handle the lifetime of your app?

Answer (score 1):

I guess your code is correct , I tested simple code and The code was implemented correctly on mobile.

try this one :

```
var mailButton:Sprite = createSprite(0x00FF11, 140, 550);
            mailButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, OpenPage);
            addChild(mailButton);


function createSprite(hue:int, xPos:int, yPos:int):Sprite
        {
            var temp:Sprite = new Sprite();
            temp.graphics.beginFill(hue, 1);
            temp.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 200, 100);
            temp.graphics.endFill();
            temp.x = xPos;
            temp.y = yPos;
            return temp;
        }


function OpenPage(evt:MouseEvent):void
        {  
        setTimeout(function(){NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit(0);
},3000)

            navigateToURL(new URLRequest('http://www.google.com'));

        }
```

I hope that is useful for you